# How to create objects with retrieved Hierarchical result set?

Tags: c#

I am using C# language. My problem is that i don't know how to store my retrieved hierarchical result set to my object.

Here's is my Object:

```
public class CategoryItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryItem> SubCategory = new List<CategoryItem>();
    public List<CategoryItem> GetSubCategory()
    {
        return SubCategory;
    }
    public void AddSubCategory(CategoryItem ci)
    {
        SubCategory.Add(ci);
    }
    public void RemoveSubCategory(CategoryItem ci)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SubCategory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (SubCategory.ElementAt(i).CategoryID == ci.CategoryID)
            {
                SubCategory.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's is my sample retrieve data set from MSSQL server

```
ID  PrntID  Title   
_______ _______     
1   0   Node1   
2   1   Node2   
3   1   Node3   
4   2   Node4   
5   2   Node5   
6   2   Node6   
7   3   Node7   
8   4   Node8   
9   4   Node9   
10  9   Node10
```

Tree view for easy reference

```
Node 1
-Node 2
--Node 4
---Node 8
---Node 9
----Node 10
--Node 5
--Node 6
-Node 3
--Node 7
```

My problem is how to do I store this result to my "CategoryItem Object". I don't have any clue do I need to use iteration for this? Specially when the node is 2 level-deep. 
I want to store it in such a like this:

```
List<CategoryItem> items = new List<CategoryItem>();
```

with this I can dig every objects in the 'items' object and I can access its sub-category / child / children using the GetSubCategory() method of my class. Is this possible?

Comment: why are you using one class for everything

Comment: Because I will use it to my Web Application, I plan to throw a "List of CategoryItem" to my View, so that in my View layer there I can iterate through the "List of CategoryItem" and with this approach it is very generic, meaning there's no limit even how deep the hierarchy is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that in your DataSet a node will never appear before its parent, you can use this code. Here you keep track of the already read items in a Dictionary when you can look for parents of the newly read nodes. If you find the parent you add the new item to its children, otherwise it's a first level node.

```
    public static List<CategoryItem> LoadFromDataSet(DataSet aDS)
    {
        List<CategoryItem> result = new List<CategoryItem>();
        Dictionary<int, CategoryItem> alreadyRead = new Dictionary<int, CategoryItem>();
        foreach (DataRow aRow in aDS.Tables["YourTable"].Rows)
        {
            CategoryItem newItem = new CategoryItem();
            newItem.CategoryID = (int)aRow["ID"];
            newItem.ParentID = (int)aRow["PrntID"];
            newItem.Name = (string)aRow["Title"];
            alreadyRead[newItem.CategoryID] = newItem;
            CategoryItem aParent;
            if (alreadyRead.TryGetValue(newItem.ParentID, out aParent))
                aParent.AddSubCategory(newItem);
            else
                result.Add(newItem);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If my assumption isn't true (i.e. it is possible for a node to appear in the DataSet before its parent), you have to first read all the nodes (and put them in the Dictionary), then loop through the same Dictionary to build the result. Something like this:

```
    public static List<CategoryItem> LoadFromDataSet(DataSet aDS)
    {
        List<CategoryItem> result = new List<CategoryItem>();
        Dictionary<int, CategoryItem> alreadyRead = new Dictionary<int, CategoryItem>();
        foreach (DataRow aRow in aDS.Tables["YourTable"].Rows)
        {
            CategoryItem newItem = new CategoryItem();
            newItem.CategoryID = (int)aRow["ID"];
            newItem.ParentID = (int)aRow["PrntID"];
            newItem.Name = (string)aRow["Title"];
            alreadyRead[newItem.CategoryID] = newItem;
        }
        foreach (CategoryItem newItem in alreadyRead.Values)
        {
            CategoryItem aParent;
            if (alreadyRead.TryGetValue(newItem.ParentID, out aParent))
                aParent.AddSubCategory(newItem);
            else
                result.Add(newItem);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is wonderful! It works! Thanks so much sir! If only I could give all my ups to you! Great! Thanks again sir! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to write recursive code to achieve this.

```
//First of all, find the root level parent
int  baseParent = "0"; 
// Find the lowest root parent value
 foreach (var selection in collection)
 {
     //assign any random parent id, if not assigned before
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseParent))
        baseParent = selection["PrntID"];

     //check whether it is the minimum value
     if (Convert.ToInt32(selection["PrntID"]) < Convert.ToInt32(baseParent))
       baseParent = selection["PrntID"];
 }
//If you are sure that your parent root level node would always be zero, then you could   //probably skip the above part.
//Now start building your hierarchy
foreach (var selection in collection)
{
  CategoryItem item = new CategoryItem();
  //start from root
  if(selection["Id"] == baseParentId)
  {
    //add item property
    item.Id = selection["id];
    //go recursive to bring all children
    //get all children
    GetAllChildren(item , collection);
  }
}


private void GetAllChildren(CategoryItem parent, List<Rows> Collection)
{
  foreach(var selection in Collection)
  {
     //find all children of that parent
     if(selection["PrntID"] = parent.Id)
     {
       CategoryItem child = new CategoryItem ();
       //set properties
       child.Id = selection["Id"];
       //add the child to the parent
       parent.AddSubCategory(child);
       //go recursive and find all child for this node now
       GetAllChildren(child, Collection);
     }
   }
}
```

Note: This is not exactly working code. But this would give you insight how you go around and build a Hierarchical data structure that has to be represented as object.

Answer (score 0):

Load your table in to a Datatable and fist find the root node and create root object

```
DataRow[] rootRow = table.Select("PrntID = 0");
CategoryItem root = new CategoryItem() { CategoryID = (int)rootRow[0]["ID"].ToString(), Name = rootRow[0]["Title"].ToString(), ParentID = (int)rootRow[0]["PrntID"].ToString() };
```

Then you need to call recursive method to add sub categories,

```
GetCategoryItem((int)rootRow[0]["ID"].ToString(), root);
```

change below method as you wish.

```
public void GetCategoryItem(CategoryItem parant)
{
    DataRow[] rootRow = table.Select("PrntID =" + parant.CategoryID);
    for (int i = 0; i < rootRow.Length; i++)
    {
        CategoryItem child = new CategoryItem() { CategoryID = (int)rootRow[i]["ID"].ToString(), Name = rootRow[i]["Title"].ToString(), ParentID = (int)rootRow[i]["PrntID"].ToString() };
        GetCategoryItem(child);
        parant.SubCategory.Add(child);
    }
}
```