# Building a tree out of items list

Tags: c#

I would like to get some suggestions on how I can build a tree out of items list in a efficient way

```
 public class Item
    {
        public Item(int id, int? parentId)
        {
            Id = id;
            ParentId = parentId;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; private set; }
        public List<Item> SubItems  { get; set; }
    }

    private Item BuildATree()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>()
                        {
                            new Item(1, null),
                            new Item(2, 1),
                            new Item(3, 1),
                            new Item(4, 1),
                            new Item(5, 2),
                            new Item(6, 2),
                            new Item(7, 4),
                            new Item(8, 7),
                            new Item(9, 1),
                        };

        //Build a tree out of list items
    }
```

The result I am expecting is each item being in its parent's SubItems list

Not necessarily using the same Item class, because Ids would be redundant then

Comment: Is this a homework since this structure has started to be a hot topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878268/recursive-reading-of-listobject , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827237/how-to-create-objects-with-retrieved-hierarchical-result-set

Comment: This is not a homework, I am not asking for a solution, I am asking for some suggestions what would be most efficient way to solve it

Comment: What is your *inefficient* way that makes you seek for an efficient one ?

Comment: Check out the update on post, well that is the solution which seems to be good enough for my case

Comment: @Jeff: If you have found/written the solution yourself then it would be nice if you add it as an answer to your own question and then accept it - just not to leave the open question hanging on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution which is efficient enough

```
private void RecursiveBuilder(ref Item i, IEnumerable<Item> li)
{
    var item = i;
    i.SubItems = (from n in li where n.ParentId == item.Id select n).ToList();
    i.SubItems.ForEach(f => RecursiveBuilder(ref f, li));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use LINQ:

```
//Build a tree out of list items
foreach (Item item in items)
{
    item.SubItems = items.Where(i => i.ParentId.Value == item.Id).ToList();
}
```

UPD:

To simplify moving items from one parent to another you'll need to store a reference to parent Item in every Item. Something like:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int id, int? parentId)
    {
        Id = id;
        ParentId = parentId;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; private set; }
    public List<Item> SubItems  { get; set; }

    private Item _parent;
    public Item Parent 
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set
        {
            if (_parent != null)
                _parent.SubItems.Remove(this);
            _parent = value;
            if (_parent != null)
                _parent.SubItems.Add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

If you implement in that way then just setting new Parent item via this property will be enough to modify both old and new parent's SubItems collections - but beware that you'll also need a bit more complex list initialization mechanism.

Comment: Can it be recursive, also removing items from list if it was moved to Other item as a sub item

Comment: Item item in items...lol, thats got to be the most similar linq you can get without breaching on reserved keywords congratulations :P

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want/have Link :

```
Dictionary<int,Item> dic = new Dictionary<int,Item>();
foreach(Item item in items)
{
    Item parent;
    if(item.ParentId!=null && dic.TryGetValue(item.ParentId, out parent))
        parent.SubItems.Add(item);
    else
        dic.Add(item.Id, item);
}
Item root = dic[1];
```

I supposed that there will always be a Item with id = 1 and that's the root of the tree.

If you want to use new Class without the ids, create them instead of simply add them to their parents.